# What is significance of trailing "$" in some function names?

Tags: vba, excel

I recently looked at some vba source at Microsoft: [Convert Fractions to Decimal Values][1]

[1]: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/185424 and I noticed that several functions had a trailing "$", specifically trim$(), left$(), and mid$().  My question is:  what does the "$" signify?

I downloaded the microsoft function and it ran correctly under Excel 2007.

Since VBA trim() works differently from the worksheet function trim(), I wrote a small program to compare the operation of the 3 possible trim() calls.  I found that trim() and trim$() produced identical output.  worksheetfunction.trim(), of course, produces output that has extraneous space characters removed from inside the string.

I am very curious about the trailing "$", and will be grateful for enlightenment!

Thank you, 
Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/196893-difference-between-left-left-function

*Allen Browne

The trailing $ is a type declaration character for the String data type in
 VBA.
 The result returned from Left$() is a string, whereas Left() returns a
 Variant.
 You must use Left(), not Left$() if there is any chance of Null values,
 since the Variant can be Null but the String cannot.*

That post has a full worked example

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is a left-over habit from ancient history. In early versions of Basic variables did not have to be declared but data types were implied by the name of the variable. Any variable ending with $ was a string and any variable ending with % was an integer.

FORTRAN had a similar convention: any variable starting with the letters I, J, K, L, M or N were integers, all others were real.

Comment: Less of the "ancient history" thanks, I programmed in those languages!  Of course the computers were steam powered so we had to stoke up the boilers before turning them on.

Comment: "Steam"? Luxury. In my day we have to crank it by hand.

Comment: @chris, my earliest projects used rows of Egyptians, each with 1 or 0 hands raised up, lined up on the pyramids (after we emptied the rice) for easier visibility from the ground.  Each row had 1024 Egyptians, because it was 1024 B.C.